# test generated Dart code

Tags: unit-testing, dart, code-generation, dart-analyzer

## Prolog

I use [source_gen](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen) to generate [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) code. I'd like to test the output of my generator (using [test](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test) package). I looked at the tests of [source_gen](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/source_gen) and used [json_serializable_test.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/blob/master/test/json_serializable_test.dart) as a template. I can call `generate` on my generator and get the result as a String. Now I'd like to test, if classes and methods are generated as I expect. Sadly, this kind of test is missing in [json_serializable_test.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/blob/master/test/json_serializable_test.dart):

```
expect(output, isNotNull);

// TODO: test the actual output
// print(output);
```

I modified the helpers (like `_getCompilationUnitForString`) to pass a source (instead of always using `_testSource`) and get its [analyzer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) elements. Thereby, I can specify the input and expected output of my generator as a file or string and get the [analyzer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) elements of input, output and expected output.

## Approach

I came up with this primitive approach to match classes by their name and field declarations:

```
import 'package:analyzer/src/generated/element.dart';
import 'package:source_gen/src/utils.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';


Matcher equalsClass(expected) => new ClassMatcher(expected);

class ClassMatcher extends Matcher {
  final ClassElementImpl _expected;

  const ClassMatcher(this._expected);

  @override
  Description describe(Description description) => description
      .add('same class implementation as ')
      .addDescriptionOf(_expected);

  @override
  Description describeMismatch(ClassElementImpl item, Description description,
                               Map matchState, bool verbose) => description
      .add('${friendlyNameForElement(item)}')
      .add(' differs from ')
      .add('${friendlyNameForElement(_expected)}');

  @override
  bool matches(ClassElementImpl item, Map matchState) {
    return (item.displayName == _expected.displayName) &&
        unorderedEquals(_mapFields(item.fields))
            .matches(_mapFields(_expected.fields), matchState);
  }
}

Iterable _mapFields(List<FieldElement> fields) => fields
    .map(friendlyNameForElement);
```

This solution might be error-prone, since I compare fields by a String representation. Apart from this, the mismatch desciption is very poor. How can I improve my matcher?

Ps: Is there a better way to compare generated code with expectations?